# Laravel fromTable not working on model updateOrCreate function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to change the model's table when using the update or create function, but it always uses the default database table which would be "Payouts"
I am trying to change the table to "skyrim" by using the fromTable function.

```
$cluster_payout = 'skyrim';
    $user_payout = Payout::fromTable($cluster_payout)->updateOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => 1],
    ['game_id' => 1, 'locked' => 1]);
```

After executing the code, it uses the Payout Database and Payouts Table.

If I do

```
Payout::fromTable($cluster_payout)->first();
```

It'll use the Payout database with the Skyrim table. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version do you use? The last one (5.4) doesn't have `fromTable` method in Builder.

Comment: I use 5.4 with fromTable. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: You should create a new model for each table and call `updateOrCreate` on the other table's model.

Comment: Damn, I'm trying to make it as dynamic as possible ://.

Comment: There's a lot of ways to still make it dynamic (you could save class name in a variable). The easy way to achieve this would be: `\DB::table($cluster_payout)->...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this way?

```
(new Payout)->setTable($cluster_payout)
    ->updateOrCreate(
        ['user_id' => 1],
        ['game_id' => 1, 'locked' => 1]
    );
```

Comment: Same thing happens :/

Comment: This happen because the create function create a new instance from the model so the `table` value returned to default value.

Comment: so you should do it in the following way:
`$modle = (new Payout)->setTable($cluster_payout)->where('user_id', 1)->first();`
`if(!$model) { $model = (new Payout)->setTable($cluster_payout);}`
`$modle->fill(['game_id' => 1, 'locked' => 1]);`
`$model->save();`

Comment: I fixed it c: I used your code but I adapted into my own. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to vote the answer and mark it as a solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing the following:

```
$payout_cluster['payout'] = 'skyrim';
$payout = (new Payout)->setTable($payout_cluster['payout'])->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

if(!$payout) {
    $payout = (new Payout)->setTable($payout_cluster['payout']);
    $payout->fill(['user_id' => $user_id,'cluster_id' => $cluster_id,'game_id' => $game_id,'locked' => $status]); 
    $payout->save();
    }else{
        $payout->setTable($payout_cluster['payout']);
        $payout->user_id = $user_id;
        $payout->cluster_id = $cluster_id;
        $payout->game_id = $game_id;
        $payout->locked = $status;
        $payout->update();
        return($payout);
    }
```

I used @Adoudeh87's code and adapted it into my own. Thanks A c: